# Backbone.js / Coffeescript -- mapping simple click event

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm running into a blind spot with backbone.js. I've written this code and all I'm trying to do is get
the test div to render on button click. If I call `render()` within the `initialize()` function, it does render.
However, I never trigger the `render()` function in response to the click event.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

HTML Container

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <!-- / Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->
    <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/site.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/sample_data.js"></script>
    <title>The Middleman!</title>
  </head>
  <body class='page_classes'>
    <div id='main' role='main'>
      <h1>The Middleman is watching.</h1>
      <div id='band-app'>
        <button id='new-band'>new band</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Coffeescript for simple view

```
SAMPLE_TEMPLATE = """
<div id="my-fine-id">
  My fine id!!!
</div>
"""

$ ->
  class AppView extends Backbone.View
    render: ->
      console.log "rendering"
      @template = _.template SAMPLE_TEMPLATE, {}
      @el.html @template

    initialize: ->
      console.log "constructing"
      @el = $('#band-app')
      @events = {"click button#new-band": "render"}

  app = new AppView()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `delegateEvents`, which sets up the event handling, gets called in the `View` constructor, before `initialize` gets called, so either call it explicitely in your `initialize` method (after you have set up the `events` map), or make sure that the `events` map is set up as part of constructing the `View` class itself, see:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-extend

Comment: Thanks! I was using the `constructor:` function but switched to `initialize:` so as to let Backbone construct. Calling `@delegateEvents()` immediately after assigning the events hash in `initialize:` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What Marius said is right.

Typically you'd want to specify the `events` in the class definition, not in an initializer. In fact, for this example you wouldn't need an `initialize` function at all:

```coffeescript
class AppView extends Backbone.View

  events:
    'click button': 'render'

  render: ->
    @$el.html _.template SAMPLE_TEMPLATE, {}

$ ->
  new AppView el:$('#band-app')
```

Comment: And the other half of the problem is that he's changing `@el` in `initialize`, in newer Backbone's he should be using [`setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) (after `@events` is set up of course).